# Is there a point using Vuetify or should I just be using TailwindCSS or another library?

Tags: user-interface, vuetify.js, tailwind-css

I stumbled on a web app project that was using ElementUI and spent most of the year updating dependencies. Ended up installing PostCSS and rebuilding the admin Panel how I wanted it to look and feel. It way recently decided to install Vuetify as the UI components are more modern looking and they use tailwind.

Whilst it has given some dated UI components a better feel. I still find myself reskinning and re theming. In some cases building my own transitions or adding new effects.

I hate using apps that have a repetitive UI.

My question is is there any point using Vuetify as at times I find myself battling with their "skin" and using a ton of CSS !important - which doesn't seem like good practice.

Sometimes I see UI or /UX design, and I think it looks cool, but I don't always want the whole thing. I'm the only one on the team that has been fond of tackling the CSS.

Comment: Vuetify is mainly oriented on styles that are compatible with [Material Design](https://material.io/design). So if your component styles are already compatible with it, or if you can change your styles without additional approvals - Vuetify should be the right choice. Otherwise you'll spend a lot of time fixing these styles.